# Why Python returns error "a float is required" while writing to file?

Tags: python, file, api, flask, themoviedb-api

I'm trying to create files with id from database and insert some text, but it still don't want to let me do it.

```
self.a.execute(
    """INSERT INTO serial (serial.Name, Description, GenreID, CreationDate) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)""",
       (title, overview, genre, release_date))
self.a.execute("""SELECT id, serial.Name FROM serial WHERE Name=%s""", title)

title = str(self.a.fetchall()[0]['id'])

with open("templates/serials/" + title + '.html', 'w+') as o:

o.write("""
        {% extends '../base.html' %}
        {% block content %}
        <p>%s</p>
        {% endblock %}
        """ % (title))
```

If i put `%(title)` after write function, it returns `unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'str'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using old-style string formatting, "%" has a given meaning, so you have to escape it (with itself) if you want a litteral "%" in your format string, ie:

```
o.write("""
    {%% extends '../base.html' %%}
    {%% block content %%}
    <p>%s</p>
    {%% endblock %%}
    """ % (title))
```